# Running a network of two wireless routers on a switch and two different DHCP servers plus some static ip addresses

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp-server

The problem is as follows. I have two internet lines at my workplace. Both lead to two different routers. I have placed both routers on a switch via their lan ports and connected all wired computers to the switch.

The first router has a gateway address of 192.168.1.1
The second router has a gateway address of 192.168.1.254

I have enabled both devices to use DHCP servers with the first device having a range of 192.168.1.11 - 192.168.1.125 and the other to have a range of 192.168.1.126 - 192.168.1.253

All my wired computers are assigned static ip addresses on the first gateway with ip ranges from 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.10 (these are 9 computers)

I expect all the rest of the devices to connect as follows.

Devices connected wirelessly to router A get a default gateway ip of 192.168.1.1 and a DHCP ip from the range of 192.168.1.11 - 192.168.1.125

Devices connected wirelessly to router B get a default gateway ip of 192.168.1.254 and a DHCP ip from the range of 192.168.1.126 - 192.168.1.253

What happens though is that I connect my phone to SSID of router B and get a default gateway ip of 192.168.1.1 (which is the ip of router A) and an ip of 192.168.1.2 (which is an ip outside of the DHCP range of both routers)

I have really limited knowledge of networks and that is why my architecture might be bad. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:

1. router maybe has one DHCP server;
2. DHCP server maybe has one zone.

I think you doing all right. By the way your phone connects to router A.

Comment: I know it connects to router A. That's what I wrote. For some reason the DHCP server of router A is "stealing" devices from router B because what I saw from my macbook was that after I was connected to the SSID of router B I would get the correct IPs from router B for 1 second and then it changed back to the IPs of router A. I disabled the DHCP server of router A for the time being. I don't know hwhat else to do.

Comment: Can you set "authoritative" flag on router B?

Comment: I don't see an option like that.